# Displaying link if no row exists in the database, otherwise display text

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table called `flagged_posts` in my database, and it has the following columns:

```
id
thought_id
flagged_by_id
```

What I am trying to do is that if the logged in user has already flagged the post, then don't allow them to flag the post again, and I am trying to achieve this by removing the anchor link and replacing it by a message.

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
<?php

$query = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM user_thoughts WHERE added_by='$user' AND shared ='yes' "."ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT {$start}, {$limit}");

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
    $thought_id      = $row['id'];
    $message_content = $row['message'];
    $date_of_msg     = $row['post_details'];
    $thoughts_by     = $row['added_by'];
    $attachent       = $row['attachment'];
    $shared          = $row['shared'];

    // getting the id of the user who is logged in.
    $see_if_flagged_q = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = '$username'");
        $getting_deets = mysqli_fetch_assoc ($see_if_flagged_q);
            $logged_in_user_id = $getting_deets ['id'];

    echo "
        <div class='more_options' style='float: right;'>"; 
            $see_if_flagged_q2 = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM flagged_posts WHERE flagged_by_id ='$logged_in_user_id' ");
                while ($getting_deets2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc ($see_if_flagged_q2)){
                        $flagged_post_by_id = $getting_deets2 ['flagged_by_id']; 

                    // If the user logged in has not flagged the post, i.e. there is no data in the database ..
                    // .. which says their user id has flagged this thought_id.. then display the link...       
                    if ($logged_in_user_id == $flagged_post_by_id){
                            echo "<a href='/inc/flagged_post.php?id=$thought_id'> Flag </a>";
                    } 
                    // if there is data stating this user has flagged this thought_id, then echo a message
                    if ($logged_in_user_id != $flagged_post_by_id) {
                            echo "Flagged";
                    }

                }
    echo "  </div>";                
}
?>
```

So assume I am logged in as `Conor`. Conor has an `id` of 8 (id obtained from `users` table). Conor flags a post with an id of 209 (thought_id obtained from `user_thoughts` table). So in my `flagged posts` table, I will see the following row:

```
id: 1
thought_id: 209
flagged_by_id: 8
```

At the moment, neither link nor the message is appearing. If I change my query, i.e. `$see_if_flagged_q2 = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM flagged_posts ");` (removed the WHERE clause) then I get the message `Flagged` echo'd four times (because there are four rows in the `flagged_posts` table and they are echo's on every post, even those which have not been flagged by the logged in user.

**Update:**

Here is the updated code first of all:

```
            $see_if_flagged_q2 = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM flagged_posts WHERE flagged_by_id = '$logged_in_user_id'");
            $test_num = mysqli_num_rows ($see_if_flagged_q2);
                $getting_deets2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc ($see_if_flagged_q2);
                        $flagged_post_by_id = $getting_deets2['flagged_by_id'];

                        if ($flagged_post_by_id == $logged_in_user_id){
                            echo "<a href='/inc/flagged_post.php?id=$thought_id'> Flag </a>";
                            echo $test_num;
                        } 
                        if ($flagged_post_by_id != $logged_in_user_id) {
                            echo "Flagged";
                        }
```

With the above, the link appears for all posts now, even if they are flagged. I have echo'd both `$flagged_post_by_id` and '$logged_in_user_id', which both echo the value of 12 (the id of Conor from `users` table). The values are correct and the number of rows returned by `$test_num` is also correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here's a reworking of your original code. I moved the data gathering part up front, so we have a setup section before we run the while loop on the thoughts. I changed a variable name here and there. Basically, we build a list of flagged entries, and then in the while loop the job is simpler. If the current row id is in the flagged_posts array, it's flagged, else present the link.

```
// get the id of the current user
$user_id_q = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = '$username'");
$getting_deets = mysqli_fetch_assoc($user_id_q);
$logged_in_user_id = $getting_deets['id'];

// build array of posts flagged by current user
$flagged_posts_q = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT thought_id FROM flagged_posts WHERE flagged_by_id = '$logged_in_user_id'");
$flagged_posts = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($flagged_posts_q)) {
    $flagged_posts[] = $row['thought_id'];
}

$query = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM user_thoughts WHERE added_by='$user' AND shared ='yes' "."ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT {$start}, {$limit}");

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
    //You could just use $row['foo'] down below, and skip all this
    /* 
    $thought_id      = $row['id'];
    $message_content = $row['message'];
    $date_of_msg     = $row['post_details'];
    $thoughts_by     = $row['added_by'];
    $attachent       = $row['attachment'];
    $shared          = $row['shared'];
    */

    echo "<div class='more_options' style='float: right;'>"; 
        if (in_array($row['id'], $flagged_posts)){ 
            echo "Flagged";
        } else {
            echo "<a href='/inc/flagged_post.php?id=".$row['id']."'> Flag </a>";
        }
    echo "</div>";                
}
```

Comment: This seems to partially work. I had a `thought` with an `id` of `210` which was flagged by the user logged in. When I went to that thought, it said `Flagged` and the ones not flagged, provided the link, which is exactly what I want. However, then I decided to clear all rows in my `flagged_posts` table, and I then saw undefined variable errors on `$flagged_posts` and ` in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given`. Basically, when there are no rows in the `flagged_posts` table, I get the errors. If there is a row, then the code works exactly how I want it too. Part 1/2.

Comment: I have manually inserted a row in the `flagged_posts` table, stating `thought_id` of `212` (which doesn't exist), has been flagged by user with the id of `12` (logged in user). And then the code works. Seems like it just needs a row to exist in the `flagged_posts` table to work. Part 2/2.

Comment: Ah, I'v just tested again. So I am logged in as Conor, who has an id of 12. If the `flagged_thoughts` table does not have a row which has a `flagged_by_id` of 12, then the errors will display on the page.

Comment: answer edited - we just needed to initialize the array so that it's always an array, even if it's empty.

Comment: Works perfectly :) Thanks for everything!